# How to Implement Deep Cloning of Objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a challenge in JavaScript where I need to create a deep clone of an object. The object can have nested objects, arrays, and different types of properties. The built-in Object.assign() and the spread syntax ... only create shallow copies, which isn't sufficient for my use case.

For example, consider the following object:

```
let originalObj = {
    name: "John",
    age: 30,
    address: {
        street: "123 Main St",
        city: "Anytown"
    },
    hobbies: ["reading", "gaming"]
};
```

I want to create a deep clone of this object so that changes to the nested objects or arrays in the cloned object do not affect the original object.

Comment: When you searched for a solution before posting this question, what did you find and why wasn't it sufficient?

Comment: @yuekandy it's ok, to achieve deep cloning there are different way, few of them using JSON.stringify [1st serializes and then parse back to new object], or use lodash library, best and modern way is to use "structuredClone"